# url checker with includes()

Tags: javascript, typescript, path, include

i'm trying to make a url checker with js, this is the part of the code i'm having trouble with:

```
switch (true) {
    case document.location.pathname.includes("/account"):
      presenceData.details = "Viewing account..."
    break
    case document.location.pathname.includes("/mylist"):
      presenceData.details = "Viewing list..."
    break
    }
}
```

the url I am working with is ***{example.com}/account/profiles/mylist*** and when I test */mylist* it keeps showing me "Viewing account..."
what can I change to make */account* not interfer */mylist*?

Comment: "*when I test /mylist it keeps showing me "Viewing account..."*" How does this differ from your expectaiton? The literal first condition meets the definition of including `/account`. If you need to know what the URL ends with, why not the aptly-named [`endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) method...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `{example.com}/account/profiles/mylist` contains **both** the strings `"/account"` and `"/mylist"`.  So when you hit your first case, a match is made, and then you `break` out of the switch.

```js
let pathname = '/account/profiles/mylist';
switch (true) {
  case pathname.includes("/account"):
    console.log("Viewing account...");
    break;
  case pathname.includes("/mylist"):
    console.log("Viewing list...");
    break;
}
```

If you know that `/mylist` is always going to be deeper in the hierarchy, beneath `/account`, you could just switch the order of the cases:

```js
let pathname = '/account/profiles/mylist';
switch (true) {
  case pathname.includes("/mylist"):
    console.log("Viewing list...");
    break;
  case pathname.includes("/account"):
    console.log("Viewing account...");
    break;
}
```

Otherwise, you may need a more nuanced logic approach, and you *may* wish to avoid using `switch` statements in favor of `if`/`else` statements, as there are some peculiarities to a `switch` (specifically, that once a single case is met all other case blocks will be interpreted as matching until you `break`).

EDIT:

OR, another alternative would be to leverage [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) instead:

```js
let pathname = '/account/profiles/mylist';
switch (true) {
  case pathname.endsWith("/account"):
    console.log("Viewing account...");
    break;
  case pathname.endsWith("/mylist"):
    console.log("Viewing list...");
    break;
}
```

**FULL DISCLOSURE** -- as I was typing this edit [esqew posted the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829362/url-checker-with-includes/69829551#69829555).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) instead...?

```
switch (true) {
    case document.location.pathname.endsWith("/account"):
      presenceData.details = "Viewing account..."
    break
    case document.location.pathname.endsWith("/mylist"):
      presenceData.details = "Viewing list..."
    break
    }
}
```

Tangential, but `switch` statements are (IMO) outdated and become difficult to read/maintain (considering the necessity of `break`ing every condition); additionally, your use of `switch (true)` is somewhat abusing what a `switch` is meant to accomplish. You probably should be simply using `if`/`else if` statements anyway:

```
if (document.location.pathname.endsWith("/account")) {
    presenceData.details = "Viewing account...";
}
else (document.location.pathname.endsWith("/mylist")) {
    presenceData.details = "Viewing list...";
}
```